# How to automate the "Windows Security" window: "Windows can't verify the publisher of this driver software"

Tags: windows, winforms, automation, autoit

This should be a simple question that should have a simple solution...yet nothing that I have tried works. My question is why? Is there a security feature in Microsoft preventing sending keys to "Security Windows"?

[image]

AutoiT attempt (does not work):

```
WindWait("Windows Security")
Send("{DOWN}")
Sleep(10)
Send("{ENTER}")
```

I have also tried/look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16438477/how-to-get-rid-of-windows-cant-verify-the-publisher-of-this-driver-software-w)

I have tried to do this in C++ and in C# and I can only get the window to become the active window but when I send keys to it it ignores it.

Below are some of the places that I have look in order to suppress or automate this window:

[Windows 7 - Disable signature verification of drivers](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/3914-windows-7-disable-signature-verification-of-drivers)

[Permanently disable driver signature enforcement on Win 7 x64](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9b6eee60-855d-47cc-9927-acae3fb6f971/permanently-disable-driver-signature-enforcement-on-win-7-x64)

[How to disable driver signing in Windows 7 SP1](http://www.wincert.net/tips/microsoft-windows/windows-7/2387-how-to-disable-driver-signing-in-windows-7-sp1)

[Disabling digital driver signing in Windows 7](http://www.howinthetech.com/disabling-digital-driver-signing-in-windows-7/)

[Windows - Suppress "Windows can't verify the publisher of this driver software"](http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000245.htm)

All "solutions" from the above links don't work. I have been searching for an answer for more than 2 days now.

If someone can tell a successfully way to suppress/automate this I (and everyone that wants to know how to do this too) will really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to identify the window using the `Win...` functions? If so you could try using [`MouseClick`](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MouseClick.htm):

```
$aPos = WinGetPos("Windows Security")
MouseClick("left", $aPos[0]+50, $aPos[1]+100)
```

First get the position of the window, then add some pixels so that when you do a right-click with the mouse you click the appropriate button. Of course you need to adjust the number of pixels to add to the x-/y-axis.

Comment: +1: I think this might work but if the screen resolution is different then the amount in x and the amount in y will change right?

Comment: You could probably use `WinMove(...)` to set it to a defined position and size.

Comment: @0gravity: From my point of view a button which was defined as 20px wide and 9px tall will still have this dimension after the screen resolution gets changed.

Comment: And you'd better use `"primary"` than `"left"` for the `MouseClick(...)`.

Comment: @mrt: It's possible for modal dialogs to change the button positions according to its size. In this special case of the non-modal windows security dialog it's important to consider that depending on the possible identification methods your dialog size will vary. E.g. when you have a Smartcard reader installed or when you use a network domain authentification...

Comment: @mrt After trying what you suggested, it does not work...I tried just mouse move but the mouse does not moves to the location that I want. I noticed that if I take the WinWait("Windows Security") then the mouse moves. So if I run the script before the window comes up the muse does not moves, but if the window is already up the mouse moves. ???

Comment: @0gravity: Is the example from the help file for `MouseMove` working for you? I would be very surprised if not. It's basically a good idea to use `WinWait()` just to be sure that the window is there before you start clicking around! ;)

Comment: @mrt MouseMove works if you don't do WinWait() before it. I know is weird but you can try it yourself...this won't happen with other windows like notepad, Firefox, ect.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I just came across this issue as well.
I was able to solve it by using the following once the window was active:

```
ControlClick("Windows Security", "", "[CLASS:Button;INSTANCE:2]")
```

It did **not** work if I included the `TEXT:&Install this driver software anyway` in the control ID.