# Check if driver is unsigned before attempting to install

Tags: driver, unsigned

From a scripting view, can you check if a driver is unsigned - or more accurately check if the publisher cannot be verified - before you attempt to install?

Problem *similar* to this:
[How to get rid of "windows can't verify the publisher of this driver software" window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16438477/how-to-get-rid-of-windows-cant-verify-the-publisher-of-this-driver-software-w)

I don't WANT to install the driver if the "Windows can't verify the publisher of this driver software" message appears; I simply want to check.

I am happy with any scripted or coded solution.

Answer (score 0):

Signtool.exe can be used to check signature.

Please read [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551778(v=vs.85).aspx) about signtool.exe options. Signtool can be find out at %program files%/windows Kits\8.1\bin

To test a signature for the purpose of running an executable or installing a driver package, the correct option is /pa. Please refer [KMCS_Walkthrough.doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn653569(v=vs.85).aspx).
To test a signature for the purpose of loading kernel-mode code, the correct option is /kp.

Example of Batch file that verifies the signature of a file, using /pa:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86\signtool" verify /v /pa %1
pause
```

some more examples:

```
Signtool verify /pa /v /c tstamd64.cat amd64\toaster.sys
```

Please refer [MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn653569(v=vs.85).aspx) and [Blog entry](http://www.davidegrayson.com/signing/) for more detailed information about driving signing.