# Windows 7, Digitally signed driver shows warning : Windows cant verify the publisher of this driver software

Tags: windows, digital-signature, drivers, kernel-mode, driver-signing

I am trying install a windows USB driver with a simple structure (containing only the  following content -

- app.inf,
- app.cat
- WdfCoInstaller01005.dll
- WinUSBCoInstaller.dll

).
 The driver is **sha 256** signed using a valid standard **kernel mode code signing certificate** issued by Digicert. I could see the digital signature in the *app.cat* file when I am see the properties of the file. 
I am trying to install the driver via *install-shield* setup in the Windows 7 SP1 64 Bit machine with all latest updates installed( including **KB3033929**). It still shows the warning *Windows cant verify the publisher of this driver software.*

For troubleshooting this I have tried installing the certificate in the target machine as one of the  [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16438477/how-to-get-rid-of-windows-cant-verify-the-publisher-of-this-driver-software-w) suggests. Still no hope.

I have used the following commands during the process of generating the .cat file and signing the .cat file. (There is no .sys file)

```
Inf2Cat /driver:"C:\CodeSigning" /os:7_X64,7_X86

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.15063.0\x64>signtool.exe si
gn /v /ac "C:\CodeSigning\DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA.crt"  /a /t ht
tp://timestamp.digicert.com  "C:\CodeSigning\Driver\app.cat"
```

**EDIT** Adding more information.

[image: Digital Signature Information]

[image: Error while installing the driver]

I have tried Sha256 Signing also (Referring from https://www.digicert.com/code-signing/driver-signing-in-windows-using-signtool.htm  (section :Internet Explorer or Chrome for Windows)

```
signtool sign /v /ac "C:\path\DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA.crt" /a /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td sha256 /fd sha256 "c:\path\to\FileToSign.cat"
```

Still  I am getting the same error.

**EDIT 2- Adding the source of the Inf file**

Please refer the source of the *.inf*  file below (Could be little legacy).

```
[Version]
Signature = "$Windows NT$"
Class =XYZdevice
ClassGuid={ad769fbf-c592-4b8c-940a-6e3782a545e8}
Provider = %ProviderName%
DriverVer=10/13/2017,6.00.2064
CatalogFile=%MFGFILENAME%.cat

; ========== Manufacturer/Models sections ===========

[Manufacturer]
%ProviderName% = XYZInc,NTx86,NTamd64

[XYZInc.NTx86]
%USB\MyDevice.DeviceDesc% =USB_Install, USB\VID_1448&PID_4AC0&REV_0001

[XYZInc.NTamd64]
%USB\MyDevice.DeviceDesc% =USB_Install, USB\VID_1448&PID_4AC0&REV_0001

; =================== Installation ===================

[ClassInstall32]
AddReg=SampleClass_RegistryAdd

[SampleClass_RegistryAdd]
HKR,,,,%ClassName%


;[1]
[USB_Install]
Include=winusb.inf
Needs=WINUSB.NT

;[2]
[USB_Install.Services]
Include=winusb.inf
AddService=WinUSB,0x00000002,WinUSB_ServiceInstall

;[3]
[WinUSB_ServiceInstall]
DisplayName     = %WinUSB_SvcDesc%
ServiceType     = 1
StartType       = 3
ErrorControl    = 1
ServiceBinary   = %12%\WinUSB.sys

;[4]
[USB_Install.Wdf]
KmdfService=WINUSB, WinUsb_Install

[WinUSB_Install]
KmdfLibraryVersion=1.5

;[5]
[USB_Install.HW]
AddReg=Dev_AddReg

[Dev_AddReg]
HKR,,DeviceInterfaceGUIDs,0x10000,"{15630179-b622-4834-8ff7-9916b1446884}"

;[6]
[USB_Install.CoInstallers]
AddReg=CoInstallers_AddReg
CopyFiles=CoInstallers_CopyFiles

[CoInstallers_AddReg]
HKR,,CoInstallers32,0x00010000,"WdfCoInstaller01005.dll,WdfCoInstaller","WinUSBCoInstaller.dll"

[CoInstallers_CopyFiles]
WinUSBCoInstaller.dll
WdfCoInstaller01005.dll

[DestinationDirs]
CoInstallers_CopyFiles=11

; ================= Source Media Section =====================
;[7]

[SourceDisksNames]
1 = %DISK_NAME%,,,\i386
2 = %DISK_NAME%,,,\amd64

[SourceDisksFiles.x86]
WinUSBCoInstaller.dll=1
WdfCoInstaller01005.dll=1

[SourceDisksFiles.NTamd64]
WinUSBCoInstaller.dll=2
WdfCoInstaller01005.dll=2

; =================== Strings ===================

[Strings]
MFGFILENAME="XYZDevice"
ProviderName="XYZ Inc"
ClassName="XYZ device"
USB\MyDevice.DeviceDesc="XYZ"
WinUSB_SvcDesc="XYZ"
DISK_NAME="Drivers"
```

I have verified the counter signature details also. Please refer the image below.

- Thumbprint of the certificate used for cross signing (thumbprint: 2f 25 13 af 39 92 db 0a 3f 79 70 9f f8 14 3b 3f 7b d2 d1 43 cross-certificate for DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA)
- Thumbprint of the cross signed certificate which can be seen from the properties of the signed file is ‎40 01 91 47 5c 98 89 1d eb a1 04 af 47 09 1b 5e b6 d4 cb cb
  (I dont know whether it is correct or not)

[image]

Please help. I have spent plenty of time on this and still end up with no results. Any help on this would be really appreciable.

Comment: WinUSB comes with Windows 7, so you can reduce your driver package size by not using coinstallers.  Your `/ac` argument looks suspect; are you sure that's a cross certificate?  You could post the link to where you downloaded it.  Posting a screenshot of the error would be good too, I'm not sure if it's an installation time error or not.  Also, I wrote a [big article](http://www.davidegrayson.com/signing/) that you might find useful.

Comment: Actually I don't think you need to specify a cross certificate with the `/ac` argument because you're not signing a kernel-mode driver.  Also, what part of your signtool invocation specifies which publisher certificate to use?

Comment: Also, you should use `/fd sha256` since SHA1 is deprecated, though I don't think that will solve your problem here.

Comment: @DavidGrayson, Thanks for your comments. I have tried from  the following documentation of Digicert.
https://www.digicert.com/code-signing/driver-signing-in-windows-using-signtool.htm ( section: Internet Explorer or Chrome for Windows).

Comment: @DavidGrayson I have tried Sha256 version of signing as well
`signtool sign /v /ac "C:\path\DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA.crt" /a /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td sha256 /fd sha256 "c:\path\to\FileToSign.cat"`
Still I am getting the same error.

Comment: @DavidGrayson I will go through your article and understand more about this.. Thanks..

Comment: I wonder if this is an InstallShield bug.  Do you get the same error message if you put the INF and CAT file and all the required files in a directory, and install the INF file by right-clicking and selecting "Install"?  You'll need a DefaultInstall section in the INF file (and don't forget to re-sign after adding it).

Comment: A driver needs two signatures.  One provided by you, the other you get from Microsoft's WHQL after they verified your driver.  A little birdy tells me that the latter one is missing.

Comment: `Note The INF file of a driver package must not contain an INF DefaultInstall section if the driver package is to be digitally signed. For more information about signing driver packages, see Driver Signing.`